# How to find the location of a "List index out of bounds" error in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

In Delphi XE2, my program now produces a "List index out of bounds" popup dialog.

[image]

I have turned "Notify on language exceptions" on under (Tools\Debugger Options\Language Exceptions) but the exception is not being displayed when debugging.

The following exception types are set to be ignored.

- VCL EAbort Exceptions
- Indy Silent Exceptions
- Microsoft DAO Exceptions
- System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException
- System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Is there a way to capture the exception without resorting to trial and error with breakpoints?

**EDIT** I am trying to get the exception dialog to appear while debugging.

Comment: Have you verified that the application is being loaded with debug?  For example, when you run it in debug mode, an 'event log' displays the modules that are being loaded.  Does your EXE show `No Debug Info` or `Has Debug Info`?  Also, have you done a `build` as opposed to just doing a `compile`?  It's possible that some DCUs that are not built with debug are being linked into your project.  Doing a `build` should ensure that all DCUs are built with debug, unless they are part of an `explicit rebuild` package.

Comment: Can you add an image of the dialog you're actually seeing? I can't reproduce this even if I build with the release configuration - I still see the `Break/Continue` exception dialog, although the `Break` button doesn't do anything to show the location - I can double-click the same location in the callstack window, but I end up in the CPU view instead of the source because of the lack of debug info.

Comment: It shows Has Debug Info and I have done a build of the project.

Comment: "Is there a way to capture the exception without resorting to trial and error with breakpoints?" IMHO, it's not a "trial and error", but yes, you can check: **if NOT** ( ( index >= 0 ) **and** ( index < List.Count) ) **then** showmessage('caught error at index: ' + IntToStr(Index)) **else** do your thing...

Comment: If the exception is occurring in the VCL and you want to see the source when you hit break instead of the CPU view, then you have to edit the project options and tell it to compile with `debug DCUs` and then `build` the project.

Comment: I fixed the image link. I can't reproduce this dialog running in the IDE, with or without debug info. You've got something misconfigured in your exception settings. Have you got 'integrated debugging' enabled (`Project->Options->Debugger Options`)? Are you building with runtime packages?

Comment: Even "trial and error with breakpoints" can be done systematically. The debugger will halt on(after) the calling procedure that caused the error, so for your next run you set breakpoints at the start and end in that procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Additional options" box had the value -LUDesignIDE. It seems that this was preventing Delphi from catching the exception, once removed things returned to normal. I don't know if only this option causes this, or if other options entered would cause the same problem.

Comment: Where is this box located ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one of my projects, where Delphi wouldn't catch the exception and let me click the `break` or `continue` buttons.  My problem was that I had some DCUs without debug that were being linked in because Delphi found them first when compiling/linking.

One other reason that I've seen that causes this is when I used some components and/or packages that were built without debug and the exception occurred therein.  Once I built the packages & components with debug and then rebuilt my project, Delphi caught the exceptions.